# Very slow window move and also mouse pointer | Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I am upgrading Ubuntu 20.04 recently. now i am facing problem when i move window it move but very slow, mouse point also. When i open, close or minimise any window first it slide down. (its not animation, animation turn off from tweak). i am unable to  update nviDIA driver, don't know why.

Also the loader which is appear on start page is continue show on my screen